# How to use many nested navigators in Onsen ui

Tags: onsen-ui

How to use many nested navigators in Onsen ui. It seems to me that navigator.pushPage only works for master to detail page. What about master -> detail -> sub-detail -> subdetail

Comment: Following http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#PageNavigation, the first detail page is loaded well. However when I try to load sub detail, I only got the blank page.

Comment: Check out this example: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/demo/navigator_navigator/index.html

Comment: I can solve the problem by using <ons-navigator> and then many <ons-template> after see the example of MasterDetail in monaca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem by using

```
<ons-navigator>
```

and then many

```
<ons-template>
```

after see the example of MasterDetail in monaca.